# execute shell script over ssh hangs

Tags: shell, ssh

I am trying to run a perpetual script (data-csv.sh) in a server over ssh. I echo the pid created to a file so to have the pid and be able to kill the process at a later stage

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  10.0.0.1  '~/data/data-csv.sh > ~/data/`hostname`.csv & echo $! > ~/data/pid.log'`

The above hangs. Although in the server the process is started and the pid log is created the ssh is hanging

Even like this

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  10.0.0.1  '~/data/data-csv.sh > ~/data/`hostname`.csv &'`

it still hangs.

Also the server doesn't accept `-t`. The connection is closed if you try with `-t`

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Of course it waits for the subprocess to exit. It started a subprocess with a handle on its stdin and stderr and that subprocess hasn't closed those handles.

Comment: If you want your subprocess to be properly detached, redirect its stdin, stdout and stderr elsewhere. Right now only stdout is redirected.

Comment: BTW, why use a hostname in a filename if the file is stored on the named host? Or is there a network filesystem in use here so every system shares the same `~/data`?

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. Redirected the stderr and now works fine. The hostname I want it because I sent the script to many different nodes and then I fetch the results from all of them, so I need to differentiate the results

Comment: Sure, but you _could_ use the hostname-specific filenames only in the fetch phase as opposed to the generation phase; that way they could have a more meaningful name earlier (`yourscript.csv`, f/e, letting someone seeing the file know what it's for).

Comment: BTW, I would also suggest making `</dev/null` explicit. That you don't _need_ to do it here implies that the program is already closing its own stdin, or ssh isn't passing through an open stdin channel from the parent, but it's one less thing to go wrong either way.